# transpose a matrix in postgresql without using crosstab

Tags: postgresql

In order to share some insights automatically in a slack channel, I need to created a transposed matrix from the input data i have, below you can find the input and output (used excel).

Please note that i cannot use tablefunc extention.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56568719/

Comment: i have already seen the post, they used crosstab in tabelfunc ext

Comment: Not the (accepted) answer I linked to

Comment: thanks but it didn't work in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filtered aggregation as shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56568719/)

```
select cat, 
       max(lr_perc) filter (where day = 1) as "1", 
       max(lr_perc) filter (where day = 2) as "2", 
       max(lr_perc) filter (where day = 3) as "3", 
       .... 
from the_table
group by cat;
```